# WooCommerce hook into woocommerce_thankyou

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to write to a file when the WooCommerce thankyou page is reached after placing an order. I put the following in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'test_1', 10, 1 );

function test_1(){
  //write to a file when this function is run
  $contents = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
  file_put_contents('test.txt', $contents);
}
```

It does not fire and I am wondering why that is?

Comment: May be you should define the path file before… I have test this function herself, and it does nothing as it is. So it's normal that **`woocommerce_thankyou`** does nothing.

Comment: try with woocommerce_thankyou_{$order->payment_method} hook with replacing your payment method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add file's path for write the file. Here is solution:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'test_1', 10, 1 );
function test_1(){
   // write to a file when this function is run
   $contents = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
   $pathoffile = get_template_directory()."/test/test.txt";
   file_put_contents($pathoffile, $contents, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: If you are using child theme then `get_template_directory()` provide you path of its parent theme.